# Import Custom made libraries or templates with terminal just like Laravel Artisan make Command

Tags: php, laravel, import, terminal

We use `laravel` artisan make commands to create class, model, migration file. Make: auth imports bunch of authentication system files in the project directory. 
Is it possible to create `html-php` template and `import` them to our project from command line or terminal. How to do it?

Example:

`import admin.dashboard` - ( Imports custom made admin dashboard with all files)

Comment: sure, why not ...

Comment: but how? can u provide a blog link?

Answer (score 0):

Artisan does not provides any html/view template and if want you can create an artisan command. 
You can do something like this:

- Create artisan command

php artisan make:command HtmlCommand

- Create stub files(template file) with variable placeholder which will be replaced by artisan command options and generate html from it and save to view.

Comment: Artisan comes with laravel, and it needs to be called or created from laravel project. Is there any way to achieve the same for any platform like android app, desktop app, dot.net project or any other non laravel project?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot use artisan without Laravel but you can use https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console.html within any php project and also artisan is based on this symfony component. For Desktop/Andriod .net etc you need to search if there are some cli tool for them.